# Using Keycloak with a FIPS-compliant JDK

Tags: java, jboss, wildfly, keycloak, fips

I have the requirement to build a Docker image with [Keycloak](https://www.keycloak.org/) and a FIPS-compliant JDK (based on OpenJDK 8).

My company has an internal FIPS JDK distribution which works somewhat like this:

In a `-Djava.endorsed.dirs` directory, a security provider is installed, which dispatches all security calls to BouncyCastle. This security provider has dependencies, which I pull in via Maven: several BouncyCastle jars, but also other stuff like Jackson, Scala, Guava, the kitchen sink.

I'm doing [`mvn dependency:copy-dependencies`](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/copy-dependencies-mojo.html) to copy the BouncyCastle jars to a library folder, and I'm using the Maven Shade Plugin to build an UberJar with everything else, minus what's already present in Keycloak. To prevent conflicts, I apply package shading in this UberJar (package `com.foo` is moved to `myteam.com.foo`), except for the public entrypoint referenced by above security provider.

I have a little Java test class that verifies this setup works in FIPS-compatible mode, basically the test is that

```
MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-256", "SUN").getProvider().getName()
```

returns `BCFIPS` instead of `SUN`, and this works.

Now my problem is how to get this setup working on Keycloak, given that it runs on JBoss / WildFly, and has its completely own ideas about class loading.

I launch Keycloak with the `-Djava.endorsed.dirs` parameter in my `JAVA_OPTS`, which leaves the dependencies to BouncyCastle and the other libraries.

I have tried the following approaches

Approach 1:
Declare everything as a module. Inside `/opt/jboss/keycloak/modules/system/layers/keycloak` (or `base`, I tried both), declare an `org/bouncycastle` module with all bc jars and a `com/mycompany module` with the UberJar. Register both [as global modules](http://www.mastertheboss.com/jboss-server/jboss-configuration/configuring-global-modules-and-directories-in-wildfly) (KC currently runs on WildFly 18, so the global directories option isn't available yet)

Approach 2:
Place all jars in a directory and [reference that using `-Djava.ext.dirs`](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_jboss_enterprise_application_platform/7.2/html/how_to_configure_server_security/reference_material#configure_java_bouncycastle_provider) in my `JAVA_OPTS`.

Each of these have led to the identical error message:

> Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   org.bouncycastle.jcajce.provider.BouncyCastleFipsProvider from [Module
>   "org.jboss.as.server" version 10.0.3.Final from local module loader
>   @52a86356 (finder: local module finder @5ce81285 (roots:
>   /opt/jboss/keycloak/modules, /opt/jboss/keycloak/modules/system/layers/keycloak, /opt/jboss/keycloak/modules/system/layers/base))]

Can anybody point me toward a solution?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if there's a canonical answer to this, but I ended up making this work by registering my modules as explicit dependencies of the root module `org.jboss.as.server` in the file `$KEYCLOAK_ROOT/modules/system/layers/base/org/jboss/as/server/main/module.xml`.

Answer (score 0):

Sean, running into the exact same issue you did.

Getting NoSuchMethodError on keycloak startup from the server-dist distribution. My keycloak calls isInApprovedOnlyMode() from bc-fips upon startup, and since i dont have the library in my container, i get the NoSuchMethodError. I've included bc-fips,bctls-fips, and bcpkix-fips libraries from BouncyCastle, and now need to get them to work with WildFly/JBoss (never worked with these techs before).

I'm going to try adding these deps explicitly as you did.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).